# Using local variables inside WhenEvent

Tags: evaluation, scoping, event-detection

Using `WhenEvent` inside `Module` is quite strange. The local variables are not evaluated in `WhenEvent`. For example

```
eq = Module[{time1 = 200, time2 = 400},
  {WhenEvent[t > time1, a[t] -> 1],
   WhenEvent[t > time2, a[t] -> 0]}]
```

returns

```
{WhenEvent[t > time1$1064, a[t] -> 1], 
 WhenEvent[t > time2$1064, a[t] -> 0]}
```

I guess it has something to do with the attribute of the `WhenEvent`?

```
Attributes[WhenEvent]
(* {HoldAll, Protected} *)
```

Is there anyway to force the local variables in `WhenEvent` to be evaluated?

Comment: Yes, it's related to `HoldAll`: `Module[{a = 1}, Hold@a]`.

Comment: @xzczd how can I solve this problem then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's related to `HoldAll`, so, just `Evaluate`:

```
Module[{time = 200}, WhenEvent[t > time // Evaluate, a[t] -> 1]]
```

Alternatively, use `With` instead:

```
With[{time = 200}, WhenEvent[t > time, a[t] -> 1]]
```

To understand the behavior of `With` you may want to read:

[What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/1871)