Unevaluated indexed variable in the events when using Table or Array generating a list of events
I want to use Table or Array to generate a list of events for NDSolve, but the variables (gap[k]) in the rules of the events are not being assigned their values. Is there a simple way to modify this?
I found some answers related to my problem (here and here), but they don't seem to solve it.
Clear["Global`*"];

nk = 3;
Table[gap[k] = k, {k, nk}];

Table[With[{ki = k},
{WhenEvent[f[ki][t] == 0, {c[ki][t] -> d[ki][t] + gap[ki]}]}],{k, 1, nk}]

Array[
 {WhenEvent[x[#][t] == 0, {c[#][t] -> d[#][t] + gap[#]}],
   WhenEvent[y[#][t] == 0, {c[#][t] -> d[#][t] + gap[#]}]} &, nk]

update1 : my problem vs. problem here
If I understand right, the answer here is to use Evaluate to force computation of variables in the event. But in my problem, using Evaluate on variable gap[k] is not working. Please check the result of the following code.
Table[With[{ki = k}, {WhenEvent[Evaluate@gap[ki] + f[ki][t] == 0, 
{c[ki][t] -> d[ki][t] + Evaluate@gap[ki]}]}], {k, 1, nk}]


Another related post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/221480/1871 And, you should have put more effort in understanding the answer you've received: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/298317/1871

@xzczd Thanks for your help as always. I tried to show that why my problem is different from the answer your suggsted. Please see the update.

…Your update clearly shows you don't understand the linked answers and the usage of Evaluate: Table[With[{ki = k}, {WhenEvent[     Evaluate[gap[ki] + f[ki][t] == 0], {c[ki][t] ->        d[ki][t] + Evaluate@gap[ki]}]}], {k, 1, nk}] As mentioned in Details section of document of Evaluate: "Evaluate only overrides HoldFirst etc. attributes when it appears directly as the head of the function argument that would otherwise be held. "

@xzczd Thanks, now I see the difference. I agreed to close this post.  Or maybe it is better to delete this post? Have a nice day, thanks.

Since now there's an upvoted answer, I don't think you're able to delete it :) . Just keep it as a road sign.

Ok, thanks again for your excelent explanation on Evaluate.

This is because function WhenEvent has attribute HoldAll:
Attributes[WhenEvent]

(*{HoldAll, Protected}*)

To solve this problem, you need to map Evaluate to WhenEvent at the second  argument, like
Table[With[{ki = k}, {MapAt[Evaluate, 
    WhenEvent[f[ki][t] == 0, {c[ki][t] -> d[ki][t] + gap[ki]}], 
    2]}], {k, 1, nk}]

(*{{WhenEvent[f[1][t] == 0, {c[1][t] -> 1 + d[1][t]}]}, {WhenEvent[
   f[2][t] == 0, {c[2][t] -> 2 + d[2][t]}]}, {WhenEvent[
   f[3][t] == 0, {c[3][t] -> 3 + d[3][t]}]}}*)

